# Django Slug URL Not Showing Page

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django to create events, and each even will occasionally have announcements to inform members who are enrolled in them. So I created two models, one for the event, the other for announcements. Here are the relevant portions of my source code:

models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Fund, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Announcement(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Message, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
def announcement(request, event_slug, announcement_slug):
    context_dict = {}

    event = get_object_or_404(Event, slug=event_slug)
    context_dict['event'] = event

    announcement = Announcement.objects.filter(slug=announcement_slug)
    context_dict['announcement'] = announcement

    return render(request, 'funds/announcement.html', context_dict)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from apps.funds import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.fund_details, name='fund details'),
     #This works:
     url(r'^(?P<event_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<share_class_slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.share_class_details, name='share class details'),
    # This does not work:
    url(r'^(?P<event_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<announcement_slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.announcement, name='announcement'), 
)
```

However, whenever I visit the url (my-event/annoucement-title), I get what ever is in my base.html file (a navigation bar, header, footer) however I did not include the base.html in my 'annoucement.html' file, all that is in it is the text 'hello, world.'

Comment: can you show the complete the urls.py?

Comment: Sure, i just made an edit to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you visit `my-event/annoucement-title` url this will match `share class details` url pattern first and will never reach the `announcement` url pattern. To solve this you can do like:

```
 url(r'^class-detail/(?P<event_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<share_class_slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.share_class_details, name='share class details'),

 url(r'^event-announcement/(?P<event_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<announcement_slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.announcement, name='announcement'),
```

Now if you visit `event-announcement/my-event/annoucement-title` it will match the `announcement` url pattern.